# Explicit casting of ptr to "ptr to a ptr"

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I came across this code in an interview.

```
int main()
{
    int **p;
    p = (int **) new int(7);
    cout<<*p; 
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting some run time error at *p. But when I ran the code , it executed successfully with output "0x7". Can someone please explain me how is this working. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A basic rule of thumb is that if you have to cast, you are doing it wrong. Since `new int(7)` returns `int*`, you needed to cast. But casting does not make the code right. It just papers of the fact that you got it wrong. Remove the cast and work from there.

Comment: @David: code is perhaps from interview, not from the OP.

Comment: @ David Heffernan : This is an interview question in a written exam. There were four options compile time error, run time error , code will run fine and none of above. Even I don't understand what kind of knowledge they are trying to gauge by such interview questions.

Comment: Yes, so the correct answer should have been "implementation dependent". For instance, on platforms where a pointer is not the same size as an int, this will fail horribly.

Comment: @Mr Lister: most probably, this wouldn't fail even if sizeof (int) != sizeof(pointer). It will just overwrite some memory, but the chances are high that this won't crash the program.

Comment: Well, it will read from unallocated memory. The best that can happen is that it prints some random number. As long as we agree that either "run time error" or "runs fine" is possible, depending on the situation.

Comment: @CppLearner I would add option `e) UB` and circle that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper answer would be *None of the above* unless you are given some extra constraints. Basically the code is allocating an `int` and interpreting that memory as if it was an `int*` (through a `reinterpret_cast`). The first problem is that, being a `reinterpret_cast`, the result is *unspecified* in the general case, and if the size of `int` is smaller than the size of `int*` (think a 64bit architecture) the result is *undefined behavior* as you are reading beyond the size allocated in the `new` call.

Comment: When you cast a int (32 bit) to a int* (64 bit) the result is extended to 64 bit.

Comment: @gulyan But in this case, the compiler doesn't know it should do that kind of cast. The only cast that does take place is from int* to int**, in the line above!

Comment: @gulyan: No, in a `static_cast` from a 32 bit integer to a 64 bit integer, the compiler will perform the conversion extending the size, but in a `reinterpret_cast` as is the case, it will just add code to *reinterpret* the memory. That is, it will get the pointer to the `int` and read the next 64 bits (8 bytes) as if it was an `int*`, and that is undefined behavior. That is one of the biggest problems with C style casts, it is not as clear as explicit C++ casts

Answer (score 4):

You create a new int and initialize it with value 7.

```
int *x = new int(7);
```

You than cast it to a pointer (eg memory address 7 or 0x07)

```
int **p = (int**) new int(7);
```

Then you show this address with cout.

```
*p is equal to (int*)7
```

It's a pointer with value 7.

Comment: This seems to indicate that the code is correct, or that at least it will produce the same output in every situation, while it does not. The dereference of `p` causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
new int(7);
```

allocates memory for an `int` whose value is `7` and returns a pointer to it.

```
int **p = (int **) new int(7);
```

tells the compiler to interpret that memory as an `int**`.

```
cout << *p;
```

tells the compiler that at the address `*p` is an `int *` and to output its value. The value is `0x07`. (it treats the int `7` as an address). An extra dereference would result in a crash (well, undefined behavior to be precise).

Comment: The code as it is is already undefined behavior... no need to perform an extra dereference.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore : Thanks, it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int **p;                  // declare pointer to pointer called p
    p = (int **) new int(7);  // new allocates integer initialized to value of 7 and returns a pointer.  Cast the pointer to a point to pointer.  p now represents a pointer to a pointer with contents of 0x7.  If you called **p you would get the contents at address 0x7.
    cout << *p; // dereference p, this yields a pointer, which is an int of value 0x7.
}
```

The question was most likely meant to test your knowledge of pointers, but doesn't seem very practical.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int **p = (int **) new int(7);
    cout << *p;
}
```

So, `new int(7)` allocates `sizeof(int)` bytes of memory and returns a pointer to it.  Let's say that the memory happens to be at address X.  Then X is cast to `(int**)` and stored in `p`.

`*p` dereferences the `int**`, which means it intreprets the `int` value 7 at address `X` as an `int*`.

- If `sizeof(int*)` is larger than `sizeof(int)`, then reading as an `int*` will read beyond the buffer allocated with `new` - always undefined behaviour regardless of the data types and any reintrepretation.
- If it is the same size, the CPU will attempt to read the memory containing the integer 7 as an `int*` - this will typically yield the value `int*(7)`, but looking at the Standard 5.2.10.5:

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer.* 
>   [Footnote: Converting an integral constant expression (expr.const) with value zero always yields a null pointer (conv.ptr), but converting other expressions that happen to have value zero need not yield a null pointer. --- end foonote]
>   A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.

So, the integer value is guaranteed to convert to some pointer value - nothing undefined - but the value is implementation defined.  Still, being a reversible operation it's *overwhelmingly likely* that the `int` 7 will yield an `int*` with value 7 - that explains the observed behaviour of outputting "7".

- If the pointer size is smaller than the `int` size, it will read a slice of the `int` value and interpret that as a pointer.  Depending on endianness that slice may be 0 or 7 or even something else, but again as an `int` it must be convertible to some pointer value that will be displayed.